# Watcher in elasticsearch for High CPU usage

Tags: elasticsearch, metricbeat, elasticsearch-x-pack

I want to set watcher send mail to if usage of CPU in last X minutes over N%.

First elasticsearch get data from remote server through metricbeat on each minutes. Then i want to by using that data inform administrator off high CPU usage on remote sever.

I setup mail and i finish part if Memory usage is high, but problem is with CPU usage, is 4core processor. I don't to write aggs function and condition. I try something with code from [github](https://github.com/elastic/Example-Watches/tree/master/cpu_iowait_hosts) but i can't change function to work with metricbeat.

Answer (score 2):

this worked for me. It sends mails whenever a host informs 5 hits (> 95% CPU) in a minute:

```
{
  "trigger": {
    "schedule": {
      "interval": "1m"
    }
  },
  "input": {
    "search": {
      "request": {
        "search_type": "query_then_fetch",
        "indices": [
          "metricbeat-*"
        ],
        "types": [],
        "body": {
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "filter": [
                {
                  "range": {
                    "@timestamp": {
                      "gte": "now-{{ctx.metadata.window_period}}"
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  "range": {
                    "system.process.cpu.total.pct": {
                      "gte": "{{ctx.metadata.threshold}}"
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "condition": {
    "compare": {
      "ctx.payload.hits.total": {
        "gte": 5
      }
    }
  },
  "actions": {
    "email_me": {
      "throttle_period_in_millis": 300000,
      "email": {
        "profile": "standard",
        "attachments": {
          "datalles.json": {
            "data": {
              "format": "json"
            }
          }
        },
        "from": "xxxx@gmail.com",
        "to": [
          "yyyy@gmail.com"
        ],
        "subject": " CPU overhead",
        "body": {
          "html": "The following hosts are running over {{ctx.metadata.threshold}}% CPU: <br><br>{{#ctx.payload.hits.hits}} <b>{{_source.beat.hostname}}</b> ({{_source.system.process.cpu.total.pct}}%) <br> {{/ctx.payload.hits.hits}}"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "metadata": {
    "window_period": "1m",
    "threshold": 0.95
  }
}
```

Comment: Where do you get the docs of this template languages, like {{#xxx}} ... {{/xxx}}?

Comment: I believe you are looking for [mustache](https://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html)

Comment: My question is does this query will look for average CPU usage or highest CPU usage percentage for last 1 minute.